# Commuting Matrices, Hermitian Matrices, and Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be any real $d\times d$ real matrix. Let $H = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$, $S = \frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$. Suppose $H$ is Hermitian (which is obvious) and $KS$ is Hermitian, and $Hu = \lambda u$ with $u \ne 0$. Show that, if $H$ and $K$ commute, then $u$ is an eigenvector of $K$.

I have shown:

1. $Ku$ is also an eigenvector of H with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$.
2. $S$ is skew-symmetric.
3. $A$ is normal if and only if $H$ and $S$ commute.

But I didn't find any of these helpful showing the above question. Thanks very much in advance for any insights.